# how to take a symbol as a string

Tags: python, string, symbols

This question is quite simple but I cannot find the good way to do that....

The thing is that I am trying to print on screen the progress of an operation...just for test purposes, but I am having an error when I try to print something like that: "Completed 30%"

The problem is that "%" is being taken as an argument here:

Here is the piece of the code

```
print "Completed: %s % " % (100*loops/totalLoops)
```

And here is the error:

```
print "Completed: %s %" % (100*loops/totalLoops)
ValueError: incomplete format
```

There should be an easy fix for that stupid thing...but I cannot find it.

Comment: `"Completed: %s %"` -> `"Completed: %s %%"`

Comment: Why this question has been down voted ?

Comment: @eumiro We should add one then, that post clearly shows up more in [Google search](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=escape+%25+in+python+string)(44K views).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `%%` to print a single `%`:

```
print "Completed: %s %%" % (100*loops/totalLoops)
```

or use the new format:

```
print "Completed: {0} %".format(100. * loops / totalLoops)
```

which even allows you to print float as percents (without multiplying them with 100):

```
print "Completed: {0:.0%}".format(1. * loops / totalLoops)
```

For

```
loops = 2
totalLoops = 7
```

prints

```
'Completed: 29%'
```

Comment: Thanks....stupid thing but it is making me crazy. I didn't know that about this new format. Thanks, in addtion to the answer I have learned something new!!